# Why .profile and .bash_profile have non-owner R permissions?

Tags: bash, permissions, profile

On the Linux systems I've seen the files `.profile` and `.bash_profile` in `~` have permissions `-rw-r--r--`.

People seem to put various env vars into these files quite often, including smth like AWS keys, etc.

Those non-owner R bits don't make these files widely readable, because home directories themselves prevent that by having `drwx------`. Which makes sense.

HOWEVER.

Doesn't this increase the potential attack surface? What's the reason for having those R bits on by default across many Linux distributions? Any specific use-cases valid today?

Btw, `.bash_history` has `-rw-------`. So it looks more private than the files in subject. Not clear why.

Comment: It sounds as if you may be a disciple of Lennart Poettering?  I say this because of the [proposed additions](https://www.howtogeek.com/673018/systemd-will-change-how-your-linux-home-directory-works/) (`homectl` & `systemd-homed`) to `systemd`.   I don't know about the *attack surface*, but it does seem that there might be some privacy risks?

Comment: Probably just because they were copied from a template which was owned by a different user and/or with default umask. Keys shouldn't be in there anyway, there's a reason why `~/.ssh` is not world-readable

Comment: @Useless The reason `~/.ssh` is not world readable is that the developers of SSH care about security more than shell and distro people, that's all.

Comment: Yes, developers of ssh care more because ssh needs security.  shell barely does.

Comment: @Seamus Could you unfold "some privacy risks" into specific samples?

Answer (score 2):

First, the default profile files do not contain passwords and typically the information in these files is not sensitive, and it is rare for sensitive information to go in them and they typically don't change much.   If you are going to put sensitive things in them, you can change the permissions at that time.  It would be better to put sensitive information in a separate file and source that from the profile files.  On the other hand, `.bash_history` can contain extensive private information, including recent activities.

Secondly, environment variables are world readable anyway using the `ps` command, so it is insecure to put sensitive information in environment variables anyway, so putting environment settings in `.bashrc` and then making it world readable doesn't make things significantly less secure since environment variables are already world readable.

Comment: What? `/proc/<pid>/environ` is not accessible if the process is not yours and you are not root!

Comment: Could you explain how exactly "environment variables are world readable ... using the ps command"?

Answer (score 0):

That is wrong; they shouldn't be readable. They could contain sensitive information like environment variable definitions with API keys and whatnot.

In the TXR Language, I did something about this. If you start an interactive session, it checks the permissions of the startup files, and diagnoses.

```
$ ls -l ~/.txr_profile
-rw-r----- 1 kaz kaz 775 Aug  2  2021 /home/kaz/.txr_profile
$ txr
This is the TXR Lisp interactive listener of TXR 292.
Quit with :quit or Ctrl-D on an empty line. Ctrl-X ? for cheatsheet.
Merry GNUsmas, dear FSF friends! ... Crap, wait. That's 'Samsung' backwards!
1>
$ chmod go+r ~/.txr_profile
$ txr
This is the TXR Lisp interactive listener of TXR 292.
Quit with :quit or Ctrl-D on an empty line. Ctrl-X ? for cheatsheet.
** security problem: /home/kaz/.txr_profile is readable by others
1>
```

Note that it didn't execute the profile file (and so we don't see the random quote). If you create a profile file with the wrong permissions, whatever you put into it won't run: to get it working, you will have to fix the perms.

Bash history is private because Bash creates that file, not your distro, and Bash uses the right creation mask.

However, if I change `~/.bash_history` to `rw-r--r--`, or even `rw-rw-rw-`, and fire up a new Bash instance, I don't see any warning. Whoops!